# ¿Cómo hacer POST sin recargar la página?

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario con una tabla, la dupliqué para para hacer `POST` de la misma tabla pero con diferentes datos, lo que pasa es que al guardar se recarga la página y borra los datos de las otras tablas, ¿cómo hago para hacer `POST` de cada tabla y mantener los datos para hacer `POST` en cada una?

```
<form method="POST" action="action/user_save_report.php">
        <h1 id="user_add_report_header">Reporte de actividades</h1><br>

        <table id="user_add_report_table1">

        </table>

        <div id="user_add_report_buttons">

            <!--<input type="submit" class="button button-large withmargin" name="addButton" value="Añadir"/>-->
            <input type="submit" class="button button-large withmargin" name="addContinueButton" value="Añadir y continuar"/> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

Datos a guardar:

```
$projectId = $_POST['project'];
$customerId = $_POST['customer'];
$reportedTime = $_POST['reported_time'];
$reportedDescrption = $_POST['reported_description'];
```

[Pic del programa](https://ibb.co/h0BLzU)

Comment: Tendrás que hacerlo o bien por ajax, o bien recargar toda la información de nuevo en cada recarga de página.

Comment: Gracias cual me recomienda mas?

Comment: Ajax sin ninguna duda

Comment: Como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Para enviar un formulario dinámicamente sin que se recargue la página, se utiliza la librería Ajax de Javascript. Le recomiendo que investigue al respecto, ya que su funcionalidad es muy interesante (https://librosweb.es/libro/ajax/capitulo-7/la-primera-aplicacion.html)

Comment: @Csc99 ajax no es una librería, sino una API nativa

Comment: @shadow Uf que fallo, lo siento...

Comment: yo recomendaria recargar toda la pagina. Una vez que lo tengas, ya te pones con ajax. Asi tu controlador podria devolver tanto la pagina completa como un json con los datos que ha leido, y te valdria para ambas cosas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que podrias realiza es utilizar fecth. que igual trabaja realizando peticiones ajax.
Tu funcion ajax.

```
   <script>
    // self executing function here
    (function() {

        const forma = document.getElementById("FormSaveUser");

        forma.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            fetch('action/user_save_report.php')
             .then(function(response) {
                alert(response);
             })
              .cath(function(error) {
                console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' +   error.message);
              });
        });

    })();

    </script>
```

Tu formulario solo agregale un Id="FormSaveUser" y borrra el tag de `action="action/user_save_report.php"`

```
<form method="POST"  id="FormSaveUser">
        <h1 id="user_add_report_header">Reporte de actividades</h1><br>

        <table id="user_add_report_table1">

        </table>

        <div id="user_add_report_buttons">

            <!--<input type="submit" class="button button-large withmargin" name="addButton" value="Añadir"/>-->
            <input type="submit" class="button button-large withmargin" name="addContinueButton" value="Añadir y continuar"/> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

tu script de php solo tienes que imprimir un json echo json_encode()

```
<?php
$arr = array();
if(isset($_POST)){
$projectId = $_POST['project'];
$customerId = $_POST['customer'];
$reportedTime = $_POST['reported_time'];
$reportedDescrption = $_POST['reported_description'];
    $arr = array( "customerId" => $customerId );
}else{
    $arr = array("Error" => "Error")
}


  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Ajustalo a tu necesidad, ahi no necesitas cargar Jquey. prueba y error.

espero haberte apoyado.
Saludos

Comment: No le agregues la extensión js a fetch pues se entiende como si fuera una librería

Comment: Verificalo amigo. es un error de syntaxis

Comment: que error te arroja?

Comment: Podrias actualizar la pregunta agregando el codigo que utilizas?

Comment: El codigo, puedes editar la pregunta y agregarlo

Comment: Listo, ahora me sale un aviso 
[object Response]

Comment: Que bueno, ya haces petición al servidor. puedes marcar la pregunta como buena

Comment: Pero necesito guardar los datos y eso no lo esta haciendo

Comment: Agrega la sentencia sql dentro de la sentencia de control IF, para poder realizar el guardado, ahi no sé, si utilizas mysqli o PDO.. se queda a tu criterio.

Comment: Tengo esta funcion 
    `public function addReport($userId, $projectId, $customerId, $time, $description) {
        $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO report (user_id,project_id,customer_id,date,time_hours,description) VALUES ('%d','%d','%d','%s','%f','%s')",
            $userId,$projectId, $customerId, date('Y-m-d'),$time, $description);
        return $this->query($sql);
    }`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84308/discussion-between-juanl-and-saul-salazar).

Comment: no funciona sigue recargando no se si es por que estoy trabajando con node y express